# Anthology with "13th floor" story, a man called Richard Javelin and a Bonanza store which has everything

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

Looking for the title of an anthology of short stories I read as a youth.

The story I remember was an eerie one about an anthropologist called Richard Javelin who enters a department store called the Bonanza, looking for a water distilling outfit. He takes an elevator to I think the 13th floor which turns out later not to exist. I remember the store's catch line, "If the Bonanza doesn't have it, it isn't".

Comment: Given the answer, I find it hard to believe that you couldn't have found this by simply Googling the main keyphrase of your question: "thirteenth floor".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Strange, when I google ["thirteenth floor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thirteenth_Floor), I get links to a film which is based on a novel by Daniel F. Galouye, with no mention of Richard Javelin :)

Answer (score 21):

The story is "The Thirteenth Floor" by Frank Gruber, which you can read online [here](http://www.unz.org/Pub/WeirdTales-1949jan-00034), and a bibliography showing various magazines and anthologies it's been published in can be found [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74109). The first line:

> The motto of *The Bonanza Store* was: "If *The Bonanza* Hasn't Got It, It Isn't."

The story also features a character with the name "Richard Javelin". He is just referred to as "Javelin" in most of the story, but on p. 37 of the version I linked to, he asks to have an item sent to the Alonzo Apartments, and the salesgirl takes his name and address, which he gives as:

> "Dick, I mean Richard Javelin. Alonzo Apartments, East Ohio Street."

Comment: Many thanks for your help,cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Gruber's story is not the one Styre was looking for.  I remember the story from a sci-fi anthology from the late 50's or early 60's.  It was called "The Tenants," and I have been unable to locate it either.  The anthology may have been one of the series of *The Best of Fantasy Science Fiction* or a similar publication.

Interesting to me that when one looks in major or minor book stores today, you will not often find anything like a 'sci-fi anthology'.  Most of what is seen to be 'sci-fi' seems to be of the *Star Wars* variety, and the idea of an 'anthology' seems to be dying.  You will have to scour the used-book store circuit instead.

Comment: While the previous answer wasn't accepted, note that the OP commented on it in such a way that leads one to believe it was correct - especially since so many of the specific details line up. What specifics do you recall form "The Tenants" that make it a better fit?

Comment: You must be thinking of ["The Tenants"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45594) by William Tenn which is also a story about a 13th floor; you can read it for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v006n04_1954-04/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v006n04_1954-04#page/n1/mode/2up). However, "The Tenants" does not have a character named Richard Javelin or a store called the Bonanza, so I'm sure Gruber's story is the one Styre was looking for. If you're looking for a different story, you should post a **question**, not an **answer**.